# why jstack not working when the /tmp/.java_pid<num> socket file has been deleted

Tags: java, sockets, jvm, jstack

Usually, I use jstack to check if the java process is working normally. While i found, when the `/tmp/java_pid<num>` (the num is pid of java process) socket file has been deleted, jstack will not work. like this:

```
[xxx]$ jstack -l 5509

5509: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
The -F option can be used when the target process is not responding
```

(PS. I didn't want to use the "-F", there may be other problems)

Is there any way to change the socket file location(not /tmp)? or to generate the socket file again when found not existed? Now what i did is to restart the java process again, a very bad solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/tmp/.java_pid` socket is used by HotSpot [Dynamic Attach](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/Serviceability.html#battach) mechanism. It is the way how `jstack` and other utilities communicate with JVM.

You cannot change the path - it is hardcoded in JVM source code. Neither you can force JVM to regenerate it, because the Attach Listener is initialized only once in HotSpot lifetime.

`jstack -F` works in a [quite different way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30682087/3448419).

In order to check whether Java process works fine, I suggest using [JMX remote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html).

**UPDATE:** as a result of [JDK-8225690](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8225690) fix, starting from JDK 14 / 11.0.13 / 8u332, JVM automatically re-creates .java_pid attach socket if has been deleted.

Comment: Thanks you! we just want to get dump info. I check the "Dynamic Attach", and found the "sendQuitTo". this is very helpful!. We can use "kill -3" to get the info, which get rid of socket file.